Is there any way to automate the check of Google Tag Manager tags and Data Layer values?
We manually check Google Tag Manager tags and Data Layer values on our website. I wonder if there is a way to automate it. If so, how can I do it?
I searched Google but cannot find proper answers to my questions. I would be very pleased if you help me.

I think tool recommendations are not really on topic (long time since I checked the rules), but with e.g. playwright (https://playwright.dev/) you can run automanted tests and check the network requests to see if your marketing tags are being triggered. They have a Github action, so you could put your tests on Github and run a scheduled action from there.

Thank you for reminder, I deleted the tool question. I'll check Playwright, thanks. But also I want to check values on Data Layer with an automation, not only tags.

There's a built-in solution in GTM for templates only. Templates have the ability to use unit testing for their code.
Besides, there are a lot of services that offer analytics testing, but it's often better to configure your own framework like Puppeteer, Selenium or Playwright.
Finally, GTM has an API that allows you to get all the content. You could implement custom unit tests for tags and variables that are not templates.
